# How can put different watermarks on even an odd pages using draftwatermark

Tags: page-numbering, draftwatermark

How can I put different watermarks on even and odd pages using `draftwatermark` package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `draftwatermark` package doesn't directly provide an interface to do this, but it can be done without modifying the package internals at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\makeatletter
\SetWatermarkText{%
    \ifodd\c@page
        Odd page
    \else
        Even page
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```